# Correct syntax for "And" statement

Tags: sql, vba

What is the correct syntax for this statement?

```
select * 
from table 
where date = mydate and product = myproduct
```

Currently written:

```
StrSQLGetProduct = "select * from RawDailySalesFromCashier Where DS_Date = #" ,&, PlanningDate & "#, & DS_ProductCode = Product_Code;"
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `PlanningDate`? And why aren't you using parameterized queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM RawDailySalesFromCashier 
WHERE DS_Date = ? 
  AND PlanningDate = ? 
  AND DS_ProductCode = Product_Code;
```

Comment: You're using `?` for parameters (_good_), but you haven't posted the VBA code to bind those parameters.